# PhpStorm multiple project navigation, quick switch between projects

Tags: phpstorm

How can I open few projects in left work area in PhpStorm? I need to quick switch between projects.

[image: multiple project navigation phpstorm]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to open more than one project in this way (and by this I mean so they have their own *different settings*), then currently it is not possible.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-15187 -- vote/star/comment to get notified on progress.

---

If you need to include files from those projects for reference purposes (to see how you have done it there, to copy some code from there etc) -- you can include them under "External Libraries" -- `Settings | PHP | Include paths`. Files included this way are protected from modifications.

---

If you need to modify those files ... you can add them into actual project as Additional Content Root (`Settings | Directories| Add Content Root`) -- such folders will be treated as part of the actual project with no separate settings.

---

Other than that -- <kbd>Alt + Tab</kbd> (or whatever the shortcut is on your OS) to switch between different PhpStorm windows (each project is opened in separate window/frame).

Comment: @LazyOne I think it is worth noting you can use the keystroke **F4** (very easy indeed) to open the included paths. Included paths can also be modified, if you try to modify them, a prompt will ask if you are sure to perform such a task.

Comment: @발렌텐 The main idea of include paths is to use them as Libraries, which basically means "read-only mode". While it's definitely possible to do what you have mentioned, it's still better keep this way and not get used to "bad habits" (lets keep oranges and apples separately) -- otherwise in next project you will accidentally edit wrong file where you should not had to. Plus, it does not makes them proper projects anyway -- Settings are applied for current project only.

Answer (score 8):

This is a right on time answer.

It is possible to quick switch between project by adding a keyboard shortcut to the "manage project" menu.

To do just that, go to `Settings > Keymap` and search for `"Manage Projects"`. Then add it the keyboard shortcut you desire and you're all set.

Hope this will help someone looking for an answer like I did.

Answer (score 1):

As LazyOne said, you can add paths to your project from `Setting | PHP | Include paths` or from the useful keystroke <kbd>F4</kbd>.

But I'd like to also share how I organise my projects, I think when you create a project, you should not open a new window but instead open it in the same window.
This way you don't get confused between the different opened windows.

In `settings` you can assign a keystroke to `Reopen recent projects`. I then use <kbd>ctrl + shift + R</kbd> but it is up for you to chose the keystroke you like.

Hope this will help you as I struggled as well to find a way to manage all my current projects.